# How to make input cancelable ? event.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript

I have an input field in my twig block. Now when I check to see if the event is cancelable, it returns false.

Is there any way to make it come true?
I've tried the 'change' event, but it's also false.

```
this._dataField.addEventListener('input', ()=> {
    console.log('input');
    this._onChange();
}
```

```
_onChange(event) {
    console.log('onChange called');
    var x = event.cancelable;
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "cancelable" in this context?

Comment: @skyboyer i want do cancel the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input event is not cancelable according to documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: Okay, thank you. 
Why is it also `false` if i try it with `'change'` on the Listener ?

Comment: Same story for the change event unfortunately (not cancelable): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event